# Is there a way to have the layout initialization(async) come before the page body initialization?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

Today I was surpriced by this finding. Blazor Layout call on `OnInitializedAsync()` is being called after the Pages own `OnInitializedAsync()` and this comes with issues when I want to get, for example, the user settings and have them cached in `localStorage` so each page later-on can gather and act upon this settings appropriately.

Is it supposed to be like this? And if yes, is there any workaround to make it so that the Layout initialization ends before committing to the initialization of pages?

Or there is another possibility, which is: given that all this calls are asyncronous(both the savings to the `localStorage` and the `GET` of the user settings) there might be a timeframe where one task is completed quicker than the other.

Comment: What you describe is a job for a *service*, not the layout. These settings have nothing to do with what's displayed to the user, so they shouldn't be stored and managed by components or pages.

Comment: So you are suggesting that this service does it's job on each page instead-of at the layout step?

Comment: Yeah, Blazor does a couple passes by design.  There are already quite a lot of questions about it on SO, and the answers explain WHY this is a good idea, and also how to change the setting if you want to.

Comment: @Eugene a service would do the job by itself, whether it's called by a page or not. A singleton service would do its job when its instance is created. Another option is to create a configuration source that loads and stores user settings to local storage. You wouldn't try to load user settings in the layout page in MVC either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the data can change, it's not constant.

Comment: All the more reason to use a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out in the end that the best place is at the authentication step, where I can receive this extra data, save it to `localStorage` and then it can be safely got on each authorized page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same approach, then you could try using a bool to determine when to render the @body tag in the layout.

For example:

```
@if(_isInitComplete)
{
    @body
}


@code {
    private bool _isInitComplete = false;

    protected override async OnInitializedAnsyc()
    {
       // Do stuff
       _isInitComplete = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does seem working without noticeable performance loss, I'll benchmark this approach better